# Prepend() does not work on certain sites

Tags: javascript

So the following code:

```
javascript:$(document.body).prepend("Hi");
```

when put in the address bar, is working on most of the sites (i.e. this current page), but it does nothing to certain other sites (i.e. google).

I am using Chrome. And I am just curious, where is the problem?

Comment: Well, think about what `$` refers to. It's not provided by the browser and it's not an ECMAScript API, so it's...........

Comment: If they don't use jQuery, it won't work.

Comment: Oh, cool. Much simplicity! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will work if the site has `jQuery` loaded, since you're using `$` as a synonym for `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome or Firefox, they have a 'snippets' or 'scratchpad' feature (look in the developer tools for each), which lets you save snippets of javascript code to run on the current page.  If, for some reason you need to use jquery on an external site, you can save the following in a snippet/scratchpad and just run it on the page you are on:

```
// jquerify.js
(function () {

  if ( !window.jQuery ) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    console.log('jquery loaded!');
  }

})();
```

Feel free to replace the jquery CDN uri with whatever you use or a different version.